# How to create Cascading Dropdownlist in MVC5 .NET framework (Code first approach)?

Tags: .net, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I ant to add multiple cascaded drop down list. I am using Code first approach and MVC 5 .NET framework.

I have generated necessary tables,Controller and views for this purpose. I have added a screen of the view [image]

Here is the Model:

```
public class CourseAssign
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TeacherId")]
    public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }       

}
```

Now I need to load teachers and courses for a department choice in rather than loading all teachers and course.

```
Department Model properties are similar to **Department[Id, Code, Name]**
Teacher Model is like **Teacher[Id, Name, DepartmentId]**
Course Model is like **Course[Id, Code, Name, DepartmentId]**
```

In Controller class **"CourseAssignsController"** I have added the following code:

```
public JsonResult GetTeachers(int DepartmentId)
    {
        var teachers = from a in db.Teachers where a.DepartmentId == DepartmentId select a;
        return Json(teachers.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

3 selection input options in form or view code snap:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "Department", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", null, "---------------- Select ----------------", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherId, "Teacher", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("TeacherId", null, "---------------- Select ----------------", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*<select id="TeacherId"></select>*@
            @*@Html.DropDownList("TeacherId", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Please select a state", new { @style = "width:250px;" })*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseId, "Course Code", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("CourseId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

And the script in the view is:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#DepartmentId').change(function () {
        var departmentId = $("#DepartmentId").val();
        $('#TeacherId').empty();
        var json = {
            id: departmentId

        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetTeachers", "CourseAssigns")',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "Json",
            data: { countryId: $('#DepartmentId').val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#TeacherId').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Name + '</option>');
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

All this I tried from internet search. But I failed to apply correctly in my coding condition. Nothing working for changes in department options.